# Select between 2 endpoints of Api Azure Devops in Excel Power Query Editor

Tags: excel, azure-devops, powerquery

Using Azure DevOps Api and Power Query, I upload the list of projects and the list of Test Plan, but I don't know how to bring both in the same search, and then use it in a combo in excel.

**In summary, I need to bring the Project and the Test Plan list, related to this project.**

```
let
    Fonte = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_odata/v1.0/", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    Projects_table = Fonte{[Name="Projects",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(Projects_table,{"ProjectSK", "ProjectId", "ProjectVisibility", "Areas", "Iterations", "Teams"})
in
```

Comment: Hi Paulo, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this doc: [Connect to Analytics data by using the Power BI OData feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/access-analytics-power-bi?view=azure-devops) to create 3 queries: Projects, Teams and WorkItems, as below.
[image]
And then follow this doc: [Append queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries) to append these 3 queries to one table, as below.
[image]

And then remove unused columns as needed.